# How do I implement remote: true functionality without link_to?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to implement nested models, here is the route file entry:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :instances
end
```

Following is the snippet for project controller:

```
# GET /projects/new
def new
  @project = Project.new
  @project.instances.build
end
```

and project's form view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= label_tag :instance_count, "Instance Count" %>
  <%= select_tag :instance_count, options_for_select([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Now when I change the number of instance count, I need to display instance fields those many times below the above form. Here is the partial code for that:

```
<%= form.simple_fields_for :instances do |i| %>
  ...  
<% end %>
```

Basically I need to call `<%= render 'instances/form', form: f %>` from project's javascript file. It should work like link with `remote: true` option. But in this case there is no link, but on change event the form need to be displayed. How should I implement this?

Comment: when you click on `@project[:instance_count]` and change the number, you want to display a different number of `instances` input fields? Does this require AJAX? maybe it is just enough listening to that click event on that div to append a new div on that page and when you submit the form, make sure the submit works for those fields .... I am thinking of posting an answer.. Adding input fields it is kind of tricky because the form has a `token` that avoid CSRF, also the submit needs to be performed maybe with `Javascript` and you would need to create a jquery `.post()` request

Comment: Your trigger hear is the clicking on the `<%= select_tag :instance_count, options_for_select([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0) %>` so `$('#select_tab').click( // add input div to the page depending on the div .value() result );`, there is no server interaction. Then you need to do the `post` request in the javascript file with this function https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Or you can use similar aproach: render partial in initial form (with display:none), then remove and save partial fields with js and clone them to form when selector is hit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to once call serverside code because `instances/form` contains code that can only be rendered on serverside.
First you have to do ajax call(ex. instance_new_path) and then you have to render the form on that view(`instance_new.js.erb`).

example .js.erb

```
$("#new_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'instances/form' ) %>");
```

Comment: Passing the form object is the tricky bit here (I'm finding) - how would you make that available to the partial?

Comment: That have to be done on controller, also specializing can be done after full code providing.

Answer (score 0):

Standard is to make a partial called `app/views/instances/_instance_fields.html.erb`. Then you can just load it into your form and make it hidden.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'instances/_instance_fields %>
<% end %>
```

Cover `_instance_fields` partial with some kind of container, like `<fieldset class='instance_fields' style='display:none'>`. Also, you shouldn't use form object there, just go with text_field_tag/checkbox_tag inputs there. Then when you need to add more instances you just copy this hidden snippets as much times, as you need and setup proper names for inputs (to be accaptable for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`).

Ping me to provide more details and assistance. This is an approach that was used in real project. Fire ajax call every time you need to add more instances is not optimized at all.

Comment: You need to store this piece in some hidden template and copy this template for each new instances. After copy you need to setup proper names with help of javascript. Right some specific notes what's not working in approach I gave you. You should not user `from` attribute. It's absolutely useless in a case of template, because you still will need to handle input `name` attributes manually in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.js` file, and load it inside `projects/new.html.erb`, which will execute whenever there is a change in `select` value and creates a `post` request to `instances/new` controller which will render `instances/new.js.erb` every time it is hit.

```
# GET /instances/new
def new
  @f = Instance.new
end
```

*instances/new.js.erb*

```
$('#instance-form-wrapper').append(<% escape_javascript(render 'instances/form', form: @f) %>
```

*load.js*

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#some-id-name', function(){
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('#instance-form-wrapper').html('') ;
  while(v--) $.post('/instances/');
})
```

Though you should **not** use like this. Rather load one `instance` field already in your code, keep it hidden, as you already have `instance` available in your `project`. Also, you do not need any new data every time when you render it. Simply on selection of value 1 you can `show` your `instance` field and if the value is `> 1` you can use [`clone`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy it further.

Answer (score 0):

Just use gem https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon for the nested forms